# Embed from imgur

Tags: php, html, embed

I'm currently using this code for embedding from youtube:

```
 if($e['domain'] == "youtube.com") {
            preg_match('/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/',$e['url'],$matches);
            if(count($matches) > 1) {
                $embed = true;
                $embed_code = "<object width='480' height='344'><param name='movie' value='http://www.youtube.com/v/" . $matches[1] . "?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;color1=FFFFFF&amp;color2=FFFFFF'></param><param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'></param><param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'></param><embed src='http://www.youtube.com/v/" . $matches[1] . "?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;color1=FFFFFF&amp;color2=FFFFFF' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' width='480' height='344'></embed></object>";
            }
        }
```

And I want to use kind of the same for imgur.com which uses the prefix "i" for embedding. So the images are prefix+$e. How do I make it work?

Right now I've tried:

```
    if($e['domain'] == "i.imgur.com") {
            preg_match('/[\\?\\&]([^\\?\\&]+)/',$e['url'],$matches);
            if(count($matches) > 1) {
                $embed = true;
                $embed_code = "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/' alt='' title='Hosted by imgur.com' />";
            }
        }
```

But I get this error message:
     Notice: Undefined variable: embed in /hsphere/local/home/xx/xx/xx/xx/view.php on line 107

EDIT: Here are the lines from 105-116:

```
            else $embed = false;

        if(isset($e['description']) || $embed == true) { ?>
            <tr class="listing_spacer_tr"><td colspan="6"></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="5"></td><td>
            <?php if($embed) echo $embed_code . "<br /><br />"; ?>

            <?php // DESCRIPTION
            if(isset($e['description'])) { ?>
            <div class="view_description"><?php echo make_clickable(nl2br($e['description'])); ?></div>
            <?php }
                } ?>
```

Comment: This is a notice level warning. You're trying to read / access `$embed` before you declare it / assign something to it. Declare `$embed` wherever it makes sense (and where it isn't dependent on a conditional) and the notice should go away.

Comment: You did not provide the code on line 107, which is where the $embed variable is called.

Comment: else $embed = false;

   if(isset($e['description']) || $embed == true) { ?> - Line 105-107

Comment: Edit your original post and include lines 100-110

Answer (score 0):

There isn't problem in code you have posted. You've probably got some problems somewhere else. Problem is reading, not assigning value to your $embed variable.

Comment: Whenever there's a link from youtube it embeds it perfectly, but when it's from imgur I get the error message.

This is the code from line 105-107:

   else $embed = false;

   if(isset($e['description']) || $embed == true) { ?>

Comment: try to change that if statement you just posted to `if ((isset($embed) and isset($e['description'])) and $embed == true)`